# knit .rmd file to .md and save the .md file one level up with a different name

Tags: r, github, markdown, knitr, rstudio

I have a `.rmd` file called `mycode.rmd` saved in a subdirectory called `root/scripts` on [github](https://github.com/ericpgreen/Rcode/tree/master/md-example).

````
R Markdown
========================================================

I'd like to find a way to 'knit to HTML' in RStudio and have the resulting .md
file save one level up in the root directory with a different name, README.md, 
so Github will display it.

```{r, results='hide'}
math <- 1 + 1
```
````

This way `README.md` in the root folder will always be up to date with my 'real' `.rmd` file in `root/scripts`. The most I want to do to make this happen is press 'knit to HTML' from RStudio when working on `mycode.rmd`.

[image]

**Update**:

A solution based on comments from @Thomas:

````
Here is one option:

```{r, include=FALSE}
   # add this chunk to end of mycode.rmd
   file.rename(from="scripts/mycode.md", 
               to="README.md")
```
````

Comment: While not just move it with `file.rename` after you `knit`?

Comment: ...or specify an output file path up one directory level?

Comment: looking into file.rename now. can you specify an output file path for knitr that will control where md files are saved when knitting to html? i thought you could only specify figure paths.

Comment: You should be able to. I haven't actually tried it on your example, though.

Comment: you can specify output path in knit(), but I haven't found a way to specify in a code chunk to this happens when using "knit to HTML" in RStudio.

Comment: `file.rename` works. i added `file.rename(from="scripts/mycode.md", to="README.md")` in a new chunk at the end of the file. thanks, @Thomas.

Comment: one can customize the command used by Rstudio, there are examples on their webpage.

Comment: your link is broken> And also, I assume you have something like `output:
  html_document:
    keep_md: yes` at the beginning of the doc? Useful to mention this for reference?!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A solution based on comments from @Thomas:

Here is one option:

````
```{r, include=FALSE}
   # add this chunk to end of mycode.rmd
   file.rename(from="scripts/mycode.md", 
               to="README.md")
```
````

Comment: But you will need to compile the Rmd twice, right? I assume the .md is created after the whole document is run (hence after the rename call)?

Comment: Yes Matifou, you're just copying the file that was created in the previous compilation.